# Collapse Bootstrap Sidebar on Something In Content

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Using the [dashboard example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/) on Bootstrap website, I tried to adapt it to my project (ui for Wordpress plugin). First, I deleted the navigation bar and changed the code as:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="">Reports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 main">
              <h2>Header</h2>
                 <!-- content goes on -->
        </div>
     </div>
<div>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24816/

Instead of the bootstrap example, on small devices, I want the sidebar items to get collapsed and create a collapsed icon as it does for the navbar items. I don't want it to get collapsed in any navbar, I want it to create it as a new element Something like this:

[image]

Comment: May be is not the answer that you are looking for, but believe me, give it a look: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp

Comment: You mean something like this: http://www.codeply.com/go/wI8UVSSkOP